# How to inherit OrderReceipt file from PoS app

Tags: odoo-15

I'm trying to inherit OrderReceipt.xml file from PoS to change the way cashier name is displayed. So far I tried this -> put the file in my module in this location: static > src > XML > orderReceipt_inherited.xml

Inside of it is this code:
[image]

And inside of my manifest file I am calling it with qweb like this:
[image]

I got no luck with it, changes are not showing on receipt. Can someone please help. Odoo version is 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `'point_of_sale.assets'` entry under `assets`.

You can find an example in the [l10n_co_pos](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/addons/l10n_co_pos/__manifest__.py#L21) module

```
'assets': {
    'point_of_sale.assets': [
        'l10n_co_pos/static/src/js/**/*',
        'l10n_co_pos/static/src/xml/**/*',
    ],
},
```

You need also to use the module name in the file path as you can see in the example above